# Insert QGIS processed raster image (e.g. GeoTIFF) to PostgreSQL/PostGIS database by pyqgis

Tags: postgis, raster, pyqgis, postgresql, postgis-raster

I've already connected to my database by a script, and loaded a vector a layer to QGIS.
Is there a way to upload a raster layer back to the database?

```py
tablename = "***"
geometrycol = "***"

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("***", "5432", "***", "***", "***")
uri.setDataSource ("public", tablename, geometrycol)
...
# rlayer to upload
templayer = QgsRasterLayer(outputpath, str(field_id))
```

Comment: what version of postgres? (newer versions need raster extensions enabled first)

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2.24 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1):

First, you must have the raster extensions from PostgreSQL.

Then, you must use raster2pgsql.exe located in the PostgreSQL bin folder. 
Raster2pgsql.exe will transform your raster image into a.sql file.

Finally, to integrate your.sql file you must use psql or open your.sql file directly in the query editor. However, raster2pgsql will usually generate a file of several hundred MB and your computer will have trouble opening it. So I advise you to use psql.

You can find several examples on the user of raster2pgsql on the internet.

Comment: I have my raster data on my PC, but the PostgreSQL (PostGIS) is on my server, so that's why asked for a pyqgis option.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with pyqgis. The QgsRasterLayer class has no export method. 
With the subprocess module, you can't open a command prompt by indicating the path to raster2pgsql on your server?

Comment: A link to a raster file (e.g. .tif) would be enough, does PgAdmin3 have this "raster2pgsql.exe"? I've already tried to find it without success.

Comment: Normally, you should find raster2pgsql.exe in the PostgreSQL bin folder. If not, you can try reinstalling Postgis. 

When PostgreSQL 12 was released, this executable was missing when Postgis was installed. About ten days later, the postgis download file was updated and the executable was present.